# The mysql.h header file cannot be found When I run the c file with gcc in cmd

Tags: mysql, c, gcc, cmd

I am going to run the c file with gcc on the command line. After running it, it says that the mysql.h header file cannot be found. And it exists in the include folder in the mingw folder.How should this be solved?

Comment: the `-I` option is used by gcc to add include paths. Not sure much more can be said without more details/context of your problem.

Comment: The following is the command line code and results.
C:WINDOWS\system32>D:
D:\>cd my
D:\my>gcc my.c
my.c:2:9:  fatal error: mysql.h: No such files or directory
  #include<mysql.h>

compilation terminated

Comment: please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69002357/edit) your question and put your build commands there. But from what you've shown, you're not supplying the include path to where mysql.h is located, so gcc doesn't know where you find it. It needs to be something like `gcc -I C:\path\to\header\files my.c`. Or you can drop mysql.h in the same directory as my.c, in this case since it looks like you did `#include <mysql.h>` in my.c. A [mre] would eliminate all this guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide -I option because your compiler needs to know from where to include header files, also when you are building a library it should store include directory and lib directory in the system directory to be globally accessible, and you won't need to specify -I option anymore.

Comment: I’m sorry I didn’t describe it clearly, I was running the c file with gcc on the Windows command line, not Linux